# pandas warning when using loc

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have this code sample which supposed to split a dataframe into smaller dataframes using group-by and modify the smaller dataframes if the numbers in 'num' column are even:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id1': [1]*5+[2]*5,
    'num': range(11, 21),
    'x': range(10)

})
print df
for id1, grouped_df in df.groupby('id1'):
    grouped_df.loc[grouped_df['num'] % 2 == 0, 'num'] = 'even'
    print grouped_df

print df
```

however when I run this code I encounter the warning:

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:537:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

and the code is extremely slow when ran on "real" data.

According to what I understand, this warning suggests the use of `loc` but I am already using it!
Does pandas view the dataframes returned by group-by as sliced? How can I get rid of this warning and ensure expected behavior?

Comment: It's not *necessarily* the case that the warning is connected to your program performance. A warning is a warning, it's often a false positive. You can try benchmarking to see what's taking time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
for id1, grouped_df in df.groupby('id1'):
    grouped_df = grouped_df.copy()
    grouped_df.loc[grouped_df['num'] % 2 == 0, 'x'] = 'even'
    print (grouped_df)

   id1  num     x
0    1   11     0
1    1   12  even
2    1   13     2
3    1   14  even
4    1   15     4
   id1  num     x
5    2   16  even
6    2   17     6
7    2   18  even
8    2   19     8
9    2   20  even
```

Comment: In my real code I need to work with the grouped-by dataframe

Comment: @MaxSegal - OK, then solution was changed completely.